# Getting last <p> tag of HTML document

Tags: html, objective-c, xml, cocoa, nsxmlparser

I have an HTML document, for example:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    </head>
    <body style="font-family: Geneva; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-size: 12px; word-wrap: break-word; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; text-decoration: none; ">
        <p style="font-family: LucidaGrande; color: rgb(51, 102, 204); margin-top: 6px; margin-bottom: 6px; word-wrap: break-word; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; text-decoration: none; ">
            fdskl says: (6:50:04 AM)
        </p>
        <p style="font-family: Arial-ItalicMT; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); margin-left: 36px; margin-top: 6px; margin-bottom: 6px; word-wrap: break-word; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; text-decoration: none; ">
            Hello
        </p>
        <p style="font-family: LucidaGrande; color: rgb(51, 102, 204); margin-top: 6px; margin-bottom: 6px; word-wrap: break-word; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; text-decoration: none; ">
            fdskl says: (6:50:18 AM)
        </p>
        <p style="font-family: Arial-ItalicMT; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); margin-left: 36px; margin-top: 6px; margin-bottom: 6px; word-wrap: break-word; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; text-decoration: none; ">
            How are you?
        </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

and I want to get whatever is inside the last p tag of this HTML. So in this case, it would be "How are you?". Using Cocoa, how can I do that?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best option is to use `NSXMLDocument`:

```
NSData *htmlData = ... // get the html data, preferably asynchronously
NSXMLDocument *document = [[[NSXMLDocument alloc] initWithData:htmlData options:NSXMLDocumentTidyHTML error:NULL] autorelease]; 
NSArray *nodes = [document nodesForXPath:@"//body/p" error:NULL];
NSXMLNode *lastP = [nodes lastObject];
NSLog(@"%@", [lastP stringValue]);
```

You should also check for errors instead of passing NULL if you want your code to be more robust.